# Spring security 3.2.5 and token based authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to secure a REST API using Spring security 3.2.5 and a java based configuration.
Actually i've found many examples developed with an "old" xml approach, but nothing with a complete java configuration.
Where can i find some useful tutorial?

The project creates a REST API and some jsp usesd to allow the admin to populate an underlyin DB (Hibernate is used as ORM):

Here is my Config class:

```
package com.idk.fantappapaback.spring;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource; import org.hibernate.SessionFactory; import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import; import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource; import org.springframework.core.env.Environment; import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor; import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager; import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean; import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement; import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver; import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer; import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc; import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry; import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter; import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView; import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

import com.google.common.base.Preconditions; import com.idk.fantappapaback.spring.security.SecurityConfig;

@Configuration @EnableWebMvc @EnableTransactionManagement @PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" }) @ComponentScan({ "com.idk.fantappapaback.persistence","com.idk.fantappapaback.rest","com.idk.fantappapaback.spring.controllers","com.idk.fantappapaback.spring.security" }) @Import({ SecurityConfig.class }) public class BackEndConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public BackEndConfig() {
        super();
    }


    //l'application context estrae il session factory da questo bean
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.idk.fantappapaback.persistence.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource() {
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        final HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        //***Proprieta per l'output delle query in sql che qui disabilito

        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }


    @Bean  
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {  
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();  
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");  
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;  
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.enable();
    }
    @Bean
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); //          registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**") //         .addResourceLocations("/css/"); //        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**") //         .addResourceLocations("/img/");
          registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/js/");
        }

}
```

this is my very basic Security config that i use to have a form log in on the jsp views:

```
package com.idk.fantappapaback.spring.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import; import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder; import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity; import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity; import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Import({ SecurityConfig.class }) nella BackEndConfig @Configuration @EnableWebSecurity public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{    @Autowired      public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {   auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("masquenada").password("123456").roles("USER"); //   auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("masquenada").password("123456").roles("ADMIN");     auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("masquenada").password("123456").roles("SUPERADMIN");    }



         @Override   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests() //     .antMatchers("/players/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")      .antMatchers("/createSeason/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')")   .and().formLogin().permitAll()      .and().httpBasic();
         } }
```

here is my SecurityWebApplicationInitializer :

```
package com.idk.fantappapaback.spring.security;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
      extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

The main question is : how to add the token based autorization?
I've added Spring oAuth 2 and  Spring integration to my pom but i need some hint about introducing spring oAuth keeping the form login.

Comment: It would be helpeful for an good answer when you post the code (that not work) and describe what expect to work as well as what happen instead.

Comment: Actually i'm still trying to find the best way to achievemy goal.
if useful i can add some details on what i've done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "configure" your SecurityWebApplicatioInitializer.

http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I'm going to try this way.